# How to download video file to Android Gallery

Tags: android, api, download

I have an url to video file like 
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/12636629_1680913862148823_1237994962_n.mp4
I know how to download video inside the app, but how then I can copy it direct to Gallery? 
Something similair to iOS's UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum method.

Comment: So, it can be done with cordova File Transfer plugin.  
As for iOS i made a plugin for this
https://gitlab.com/romanvolkov/VideoToGalleryPlugin
It receives an url to saved video and place it inside Camera Roll